# Loopback hasOne and hasMany of the same model

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I try to make a family tree. I have the model familyMember which should have two relations to it self.
First is spouse and second is children. Now I tried it with:

```
"relations": {
  "spouse": {
    "type": "hasOne",
    "model": "familyMember",
    "foreignKey": "familyMemberId"
  },
  "children": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "familyMember",
    "foreignKey": "familyMemberId"
  }
}
```

But when I create a children and after a spouse it returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "Error",
    "status": 500,
    "message": "HasOne relation cannot create more than one instance of familyMember"
  }
}
```

When I request the spouse it returns the children I've made before.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what is the name of your model for your `spouse` relation and `children` relation and the model name to which you are adding these relation??

Comment: ``children`` are many familyMembers and ``spouse`` is one familyMember. So it refers to is self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your question you have one model `familyMembers` and you are refering to the property `children` and `spouse` of the same model as relation `hasMany` and `hasOne` respectively.

Its not the best way to achieve what you are trying to get through loopback. And it has potential for error.

The best way to do is first create a model `FamilyMember` through loopback.

Then create two different models `children` and `spouse` and other related members models by inheriting the base `familyMember` model.

And then add relation between these models easily.

For more info read. [Extending a model in loopback](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Extending+built-in+models)